# Parse push notifications without gcm

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I was implementing Parse push notifications in my project but, due to legal issues, I'm not able to install Google play services, so the broadcast receiver used to receive notifications is the ParsePushBroadcastReceiver, not the GcmBroadcastReceiver. Firstly I have tried with this code in the manifest:

```
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
android:exported="false">
  <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
     <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
     <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then, I have tried with this one:

```
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
    <category android:name="com.parse.starter" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

As a result, the device have been registered with not pushType and deviceToken, showing the text `(undefined)` in both fields.
When I try to send a push to all the registered devices, Parse throw an error such as:
[image: Parse push error]

But the installations are currently active.
Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You miss the parse application id and client key (you will find these values on your parse dashboard)

```
<application
    ...>
    [...]

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.parse.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.parse.CLIENT_KEY"
        android:value="yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy" />

    [...]
</application>
```

and **also** inside the receiver:

```
<category android:name="com.parse.starter" />
```

should be:

```
<category android:name="you.package.name" />
```

Comment: As I said in my post, the app is registered in parse, so the application_id and the client_key is set in my app with also the project name

Comment: what about the last part of my answer?

Comment: it's important to change the line <category android:name="com.parse.starter" />